# How do I SSHA1 in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, sha

How do I calculate in C/C++ a **salted** SHA1 digest of a C-string (in my case a clear-text password)?

I do not want to include some huge library to do that. All I need is an "easy" way to make a **salted** SHA1 digest.

Comment: Don't use SHA1, it's no longer secure, use SHA2 instead.

Comment: Last time I needed SHA1 (it was not a crypto scenario) and didn't want a huge library, I cracked the RFC open and "stole" the reference implementation.

Comment: SHA1 is still a fine hash function for non-crypto [applications](http://blogs.igalia.com/berto/2009/01/27/git-and-the-security-of-sha-1/).

Comment: What Johan says about SHA1 is true. Depending on your security requirement, you may want to use SHA2.

Comment: And sure enough, [there it is](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4634#section-8.2.1). Even the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) has a [pseudocode explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1_pseudocode) of the algorithm (along with a history that mentions the development and existence of attacks against the algorithm), and you can still find the public domain [libtomcrypt implementation](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/master/src/hashes/sha1.c) on github.

Comment: Check out [small sha1](http://code.google.com/p/smallsha1/).

Comment: And accept an answer to questions you ask if there is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I asked for a *salted* SHA1. These solutions are for SHA1. I need SSHA1.

Comment: Writing a multi-language source file is hard work. I suggest you do not try that ... unless it's for fun.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Google search revealed this: http://www.packetizer.com/security/sha1/

Code both C++ and C, with files to include in your project (so no library). Freeware Public License (FPL).

Comment: This is SHA1. But I need **salted** SHA1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the 'easy' way is to include a pre-built library.

The essence of SHA1 and other digests is that they are not easy to calculate because that would leave them open to simple duplication that would negate their usefulness.

Comment: They're easy to implement though.

Comment: If you just have to calculate a SHA1 digest once in a while, any implementation will do. If you're calculating many every second, then the most optimised one may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, may be simple [CryptCreateHash Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379908%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will do?
By the way, here you can select the algorithm by ALG_ID.

Comment: I need it for Windows and Unix. And I'm looking for **salted** SHA1.